# Understand device tree entries and values

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I'm new to device tree source editing.
I understand the concept and learned from the bootlin talk:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz6aBffv-Ek

I have two .dtsi files:
The first is for 4.X kernel(left) and its working with my custom carrier board.
The second is for 5.X kernel(right).

I wish to apply the "extras" from the 4.x kernel .dtsi into the 5.x kernel .dtsi
The problem is that I don't know what are the valid fields that I can use and what are their possible valid values.
For example: "vdd-dp-pwr-supply" or "vdd-dp-pad-supply". How can I know which strings I can write in the 5.x kernel .dtsi that will be suitable to these strings?
the same with "<&p3668_spmic_sd0>;"

So I have some basic knowledge missing before I can start porting the 4.x .dtsi into 5.x .dtsi.

(I didn't wrote the left device tree and I don't know how the fields strings were chosen there as well)

[image]

Comment: I don't know of any better way than looking in the driver source. I even experienced a DT setting getting ignored because a typo in the driver was fixed. While it's all mainline drivers, I simply do a `grep- r` over the sources to find the relevant source.

Comment: Is there a possibility they don't exist in the driver's code (specific strings)?   I don't find the red ones there...